# Rx Operator: Take from Observable whenever latest value from other Observable is true

Tags: system.reactive

I'm looking for an Rx operator with the following semantics:

```
Observable<int> inputValues = …;
Observable<bool> gate = …;

inputValues
    .combineLatest(gate)
    .filter((pair<int, bool> pair) -> { return pair.second; })
    .map((pair<int, bool> pair) -> { return pair.first; });
```

It emits values from the first Observable while the latest value from the second Observable is `true`. Using `combineLatest`, we also get a value when the second Observable *becomes* `true`. If we don't want that, we could use `withLatestFrom` in place of `combineLatest`.

Does this operator exist (in any Rx implementation)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My apologies for giving you C# code, but here's how this can be written. Hopefully someone can translate for me.

Use the `.Switch` operator. It turns an `IObservable<IObservable<T>>` into an `IObservable<T>` by only returning the values produced by the latest observable returned by the outer observable.

```
var _gate = new Subject<bool>();
var _inputValues = new Subject<int>();

IObservable<int> inputValues = _inputValues;
IObservable<bool> gate = _gate;

IObservable<int> query =
    gate
        .StartWith(true)
        .Select(g => g ? inputValues : Observable.Never<int>())
        .Switch();

query
    .Subscribe(v => Console.WriteLine(v));

_inputValues.OnNext(1);
_inputValues.OnNext(2);
_inputValues.OnNext(3);
_gate.OnNext(false);
_inputValues.OnNext(4);
_inputValues.OnNext(5);
_gate.OnNext(true);
_inputValues.OnNext(6);
```

This produces:

```
1
2
3
6
```

If `inputValues` is a `ReplaySubject` then you can do this to make the query work correctly:

```
IObservable<int> query =
    inputValues
        .Publish(i =>
            gate
                .StartWith(true)
                .Select(g => g ? i : Observable.Never<int>())
                .Switch());
```

Comment: I appreciate it! And no need to translate ;) Our solutions have different behavior when `inputValues` is a replay subject, right? Your version replays previous values from `inputValues` whenever `gate` becomes `true`. Mine replays them when you subscribe, and only if `gate` is `true` at that point in time. Is that correct?

Comment: @basteln - You can put a `.Publish` to prevent that behaviour. I'll pop it in to show you.

Comment: Great, got it! So it seems there isn't already an operator that covers the entire behavior? Good to know, I'll create one using this implementation.